# send messages using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a table view. In each table view are different books populated from Firebase database. In each table view cell, there is a message button. When the button is clicked, then the logged in user can send a message to the user that posted that book.

```
 @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        let indexPath = self.selectedIndex
        let post = self.posts![(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.infoID = post["postID"] as? String

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMessageToUser", sender: self.userpicuid)
    }

   override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      guard segue.identifier == "sendMessageToUser", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
            return
        }

        chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
        chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid
        chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
        chatVc.username = self.username
        chatVc.infoID = self.infoID
        chatVc.bookName = self.bookName



    }
```

I am using JSQMessengerController, when I send the message, it sends to the intended user but if the user has more than one book it sends the same message to all the books.

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }


        let convoRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(convoId!)
        let itemRef = rootRef.child("messages").child(convoId!).childByAutoId() // 1
        let messageItem = [ // 2
            "senderId": senderId!,
            "ReceiverId": senderDisplayName!,
            "text": text!,
            "timestamp": NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970,
            "convoId": convoId!,
            "infoID": infoID!
            ] as [String : Any]

        itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

        itemRef.updateChildValues(messageItem) { (error, convoRef) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }

            let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.convoId!).child(senderDisplayName!)

            let messageId = itemRef.key
            userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])

            let recipientUserMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.convoId!).child(senderId!)

            recipientUserMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])

        }

        JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

        finishSendingMessage() // 5
        isTyping = false
    }
```

[image]
[image]
I want the message to only send to the cell that I click (just one book). So my intentions were to send the "hey" message for the introductory statistics book but it also sends the hey to the essentials of U.S... book

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described I believe the issue is in your `Firebase` logic. It looks like you are making a reference to your data in firebase but depending on how you look up that information you may have this duplication. If you look at your method you are using for retrieving your data from firebase make sure you are making the query based on your convoID because (I would assume) that the `"senderId": senderId!, "ReceiverId": senderDisplayName!,` will be the same for two separate books with the same author.

I don't know what this line is accomplishing 
`recipientUserMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])` but generally setting things to hard coded values (1) is a bad idea.

Let me know if that helps.